# Access global state from Light DOM within CSS of Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom

On my page (Light DOM) I have many elements of my custom type `<A>` where each has its own Shadow DOM. In that Shadow DOM there is an element `<B>` which I want to style regarding to a status (e.g. via marker class `myMarker`) of an element in the Light DOM.

```
Light DOM
|
|---- <body class="someMarker">
|       |
|       |---- <A>
|       |      |---- Shadow DOM
|       |            |
|       |            |---- <B>
|       |---- <A>
|              |---- Shadow DOM
|                    |
|                    |---- <B>
|
...
```

Without a Shadow DOM I would just add a CSS selector for `myMarker`:

```
body.myMarker A B {
  color: red;
}
```

Using a Shadow DOM within `<A>` this is not possible as the global marker class is not visible with the Shadow DOM's style context. So what can I do?

One solution would be to just add the marker class to each of my countless `<A>` elements instead of to the `<body>` and use the selector `:host(.mySelector) { ... }` to react on it. This is what I want to avoid because I don't want to manage more than one marker.

**Is there a nicer method than managing each `<A>`'s state separately?**

Comment: did you try `:host-context()`?

Comment: @Suersharp At this moment only Chrome, Opera and Android Browser support this, sadly: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_host-context

Comment: @SebastienBarth you're right it's sad for Firefox and Safari but if you want to fully use Web Components you should adopt an up-to-date browser: Chrome, Opera -and soon Edge. If not you'll need to implement a workaround by yourself, like the one you considered, or deal with css variables.